# python Filepath with spaces in configuration file

Tags: python, filepath, configparser

I have a configuration file I'm reading with ConfigParser.
One of the values is a file path containing spaces in the path:

```
[Configuration]
mysqldumpexecutable_location = C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/
```

It seems that the value returned with get() for this parameter is only "C:/Program" - up to the space.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import configparser

def BackupDB():

    try:
        config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
        config.read(r"etc\configuration.txt")
        DB_HOST = config.get('Configuration', 'db_host')
        DB_USER = config.get('Configuration', 'db_username')
        DB_USER_PASSWORD = config.get('Configuration', 'db_password')
        #DB_NAME = '/backup/dbnames.txt'
        DB_NAME = config.get('Configuration', 'db_schema')
        BACKUP_PATH = config.get('Configuration', 'backup_path')
        MYSQLDUMP_LOCATION = config.get('Configuration', 'mysqldumpexecutable_location')

        DATETIME = time.strftime('%d%m%Y-%H%M%S')
        TODAYBACKUPPATH = BACKUP_PATH + DATETIME
        db = DB_NAME

        dumpcmd = MYSQLDUMP_LOCATION + "mysqldump -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + db + " > " + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "/" + db + ".sql"
        os.system(dumpcmd)
    except Exception as e:
        print("something here")
        return None
```

I'm getting this error:
**'c:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

How can I pass this Windows path correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please also show the ConfigParser code? Thank you!

Comment: Works for me. After loading the configuration, `my_config['Configuration']['mysqldumpexecutable_location']` is `'C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/'`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I added the code to the question, with the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that five years have passed since this was originally posted, but you should enclose any paths with spaces in double quotes.

```html
[Configuration]
mysqldumpexecutable_location = "C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/"
```